# Ascertaining an appropriate test for this scenario

Tags: spss, dataset

I need to run an analysis in spss, please could you advise me on that matter?

I gave my examples, please correct me..

- three groups: control, body positivity, body neutrality,
- measure: self esteem, body image, social comparison

**hypotheses:**

H1:  Participants who view body neutrality messaging will have higher scores on a measure of self-esteem and higher scores on a measure of positive body image than participants who view body positivity messaging.

ANOVA 2x2 (BN/BP x Selfesteem/Body image)

H2: Participants who view body positivity and participants who view body neutrality messaging will have higher scores on a measure of self-esteem and positive body image than participants who view non-body-related images.

ANOVA 2x2 (BP/non-body-related x Selfesteem/Body image)
ANOVA 2x2 (BN/non-body-related x Selfesteem/Body image)

H3: Amongst participants who viewed body neutrality messaging, there will be no correlation between scores on a measure of positive body image and scores on a measure of social comparison

correlation for Body Neutrality: body image x social comparison

H4: Amongst participants who viewed body positivity messaging, there will be a positive correlation between scores on a measure of positive body image and scores on a measure of social comparison.

correlation for Body Positivity: body image x social comparison

or multiple correlation?